# Monitor and write author of changes

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium

Is it possible to monitor not only changes in database but also by whom it was changed?
Is it possible also to write to Kafka Topic information about account/login who implemented the changes?

When changing something in database I want debezium send to Kafka information about what was changed and also by whom it was changed.